# what is the difference between 'NT Authority\Service' and 'NT Authority\Network Service'?

Tags: sql-server, windows, accounts

I am configuring a SQL Server Express 2008R2 instance, and I want the current logged in user to be able to access SQLEXPRESS.

Which one should I add at the Database engine configuration step of the installation?

Comment: Neither of those are related to the current logged in user.

Comment: BTW: http://dba.stackexchange.com exists and the question would have been perfectly on topic there - I wonder why it has not been migrated **there**

Answer (score 0):

The current user will be able to log in in any case, as long as your SQL server configuration allows it (i.e. has an appropriate system login defined and a database user mapped to it with sufficient privileges). As the user installing MS SQL server is at least the local machine administrator, she will have the sysadmin role upon completion of the installation, so the "login problem" should be your least concern.

The point in being able to choose a user for the SQL service to run lies in selecting the security context for the service itself - mainly of interest if your server-based logic needs access to files on the local file system or within the network.